# Unable to convert AnonymousType#1 ti IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, anonymous-types

I have declared a model in my .cs page

```
public class InstrumentDetails
{
    public long PullNo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int New { get; set; }
    public int LN { get; set; }
    public int PR { get; set; }
    public int Any { get; set; }
}
```

After that i am retrieving data like this way :

```
IEnumerable<InstrumentDetails> instrumentdetails = (from p in NemcDb.tblPulls
    join
    pi in NemcDb.tblPullInstruments
    on
    p.PullId equals pi.PullId
    join
    i in NemcDb.tblInstruments
    on
    pi.InstrumentCode equals i.InstrumentCode
    select new
    {
        PullNo = p.PullNo.Value,
        InstrumentType = i.Description,
        New = pi.NewQuantity,
        LN = pi.LNQuantity,
        PR = pi.UsedQuantity,
        Any = pi.AnyQuantity
    }).Where(i => i.PullNo.ToString() == item);
```

But it gives me the error

> Cannot convert 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Where am I wrong?...I couldn't get it through....Please help.

Comment: Call `ToList` or `ToArray` after your `Where`.

Comment: @KennethK. That won't change anything.

Comment: It didn't work...anyways thanks for the help

Comment: Where are you initializing instances of `InstrumentDetails`? `select new` is not `select new InstrumentDetails`

Comment: Exactly ....i just missed that

Answer (score 2):

You don't tell that you want an object of type `InstrumentDetails`, you create an anonymous type. Change `select new { ...` into `select new InstrumentDetails { ...` and then also call `ToList()`, `ToEnumerable()` or `ToArray()` in the end so the query is actually run.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be :

```
            IEnumerable<InstrumentDetails> instrumentdetails = (from p in NemcDb.tblPulls
                                                            join
                                                            pi in NemcDb.tblPullInstruments
                                                            on
                                                            p.PullId equals pi.PullId
                                                            join
                                                            i in NemcDb.tblInstruments
                                                            on
                                                            pi.InstrumentCode equals i.InstrumentCode
                                                            select new InstrumentDetails
                                                            {
                                                                PullNo = p.PullNo.Value,
                                                                InstrumentType = i.Description,
                                                                New = pi.NewQuantity,
                                                                LN = pi.LNQuantity,
                                                                PR = pi.UsedQuantity,
                                                                Any = pi.AnyQuantity

                                                            }).Where(i => i.PullNo.ToString() == item).ToList();

    }
```

How Silly of me............

Comment: Other people answered your question correctly, and instead of giving them credit, you re-answered it on your own with the exact same information.

Comment: 10 seconds different between answers, could be coincidence, Voting Sami answer 'cause it explains the cause of the problem

Comment: @Aaron This answer was posted *before* the other answer.